# Disable touchscreen with Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

For my application I need to disable all touchscreen interaction. BlockInput(1) only blocks the mouse and keyboard, and I can't find anything about disabling touchscreens.

Is there a script/registry-change/hack to disable all touchscreen interactions (so the mouse can't get moved by touching the screen).

Thanks in advance,

Comment: why do you need to do this? Surely it's up to the user how they want to interact with the application?

Comment: @ADyson The application needs proper calibration. So every time Windows boots, the application runs, and it needs to be calibrated. So if they touch anywhere else, the calibration application won't start. The application simply doesn't work properly without calibration (it's a cheap chinese knockoff touchscreen).

Comment: what do you mean by calibration, exactly? Can't the application do this once it regains the focus?

Comment: @ADyson It's a touch screen, everytime Windows boots, the finger needs to be calibrated so when someone touches, it isn't off and calibrated properly. So this HAS to be done before even using the application because otherwise it simply won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Am not entirely certain what language you're trying to use. However if you want to use JS you can intercept events:

```
$(document).on('touchstart.NS touchmove.NS touchend.NS', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Now user won't be able to interact with the page/app.

This should help...

Comment: Question has been tagged as `VB.NET` however OP may be able to convert.